# IndexError - Trying to make direction string from list of lists "SESSEE" S=South,E=East

Tags: python, list, while-loop

[image: TraceBack]I am trying to make a direction string. Starting from (0,0) if there is ! on right It is EAST and 1 on down It is SOUTH.
So i iterate over list of lists using while loop and get the answer but at the end, it gives me `Index Error:List index out of range.`

```
   n=5
   sol = [[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1]]
   i=j=0
   s=""
   while(i<len(sol) or j<len(sol)):
       if(sol[i+1][j] == 1):
          s=s+"S"
          i+=1
       elif(sol[i][j+1] == 1):
          s=s+"E"
          j+=1
   print(s)
```

I don't have any clue for it?
Can you help me out from this?

```py
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "util.py", line 6 , in <module>
if(sol[i+1][j] == 1):
IndexError: list index out of range**
```

Comment: You need to post the entire traceback...

Comment: Hey!!! I did put a screenshot of traceback!!! Can you help me out fast, I need the answer immediately, Please!   @thebjorn

Comment: Nope, not as a screen shot. Copy and paste the text of the traceback.

Comment: Have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are increasing the value of `i` a `j` too much. When the program crashes, you can see in the shell that `i` is 4 and `j` is 4. `sol` has 5 elements, meaning the last index is `sol[4]`. You're attempting to access `sol[i + 1]`, which is 5. There is no `sol[5]`, which is why you get the `IndexError`.

The best option to fix this is to break from the loop when `i` or `j` reaches 4. This is done best through a [break statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html) within an `if` block. Add this to the end of the loop:

```
if i >= 4 and j >= 4:
    break
```

and it'll exit the loop when `i` and `j` are at a high enough value. If `sol` isn't guaranteed to stay the same size, you can use this instead:

```
if i >= len(sol) and j >= len(sol):
    break
```

Comment: I get it by i am not able to figure out any other way to solve it, Can you help me with a solution for this problem?

Comment: @DilipKrishna I'm editing now to mention how to fix it.

Comment: That's not giving me the right answer!!!! Of course it doesn't show the error anymore, but the last sol[3][4] to sol[4][4] is "S" and it doesn't give me that

Comment: @DilipKrishna that should solve it if I understood you correctly. It'll go through one more iteration now.